# FFmpeg make video from images skip middle or rear range

Tags: ffmpeg

From [FFmpeg Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence) we can skip the initial range of the images using `-start_number`

```
 ffmpeg -start_number 100 -i image-%03d.png video.webm
```

But how can we skip the rear part instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-frames:v`. If you have 1-2000 and want range 100-1000:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 100 -i image-%03d.png -frames:v 900 video.webm
```

Comment: I tested it, find It can terminate unpredictable at some point,  not accurate.

Comment: @user13720066 Works for me: `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=d=2000:r=1 %04d.png && ffmpeg -start_number 100 -i %04d.png -frames:v 900 output.webm && ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 output.webm` = 900 frames. How can the issue be duplicated? Do you get any errors? What is your command? Show the complete log.